# "Seitdem ich bei diese neuen Stelle arbeiten angefangen habe" - is this correct?

Tags: meaning, subordinate-clause

Verb clusters at the end of Nebensätze have been giving me a real hard time. Here is an indicative sentence in English:

> Ever since I started working at this new job, I have been really busy on Tuesdays.

Is it possible to translate it into German the following way:

> Seitdem ich bei diese neuen Stelle arbeiten angefangen habe, habe ich dienstags sehr besetzt gewesen.

I just want to know whether it's correct to use Perfekt in the context given and if so, whether the verbal components are positioned correctly. Also, could someone please suggest a resource that explains in plain and simple terms how to position modal, auxiliary, and main verbs in different types of sentences and tenses.

Comment: As a general rule, if an English gerund ("working") can be replaced by an infinitive with *to* ("to work"), it will usually translate to a German infinitive with *zu* ("zu arbeiten").

Answer (score 1):

Perfekt (DE) is NOT the correct translation for the present perfect progressive (EN). The present perfect progressive describes an action in the past which touches the present. This effect is expressed in German by Präsens.

The correct translation therefor is (being busy = beschäftigt *sein*. Your translation to "besetzt sein" does not really work in this context with people):

> Seitdem ich bei der neuen Stelle angefangen habe zu arbeiten, bin ich dienstags immer sehr beschäftigt.

or more colloquial

> Seitdem ich mit dem neuen Job angefangen habe, bin ich dienstags immer sehr busy.

Answer (score 1):

Several problems here:

- "Seitdem" is a pretty formal and rare word, better use "seit"
- Pronominal declension: bei diese**r** neuen Stelle
- After "anfangen" (or in this case before it), you use a "zu" infinitive: zu arbeiten angefangen habe
- besetzt = occupied (as in, a room is occupied, or a country is occupied); you want "beschäftigt"
- "sein" takes "sein" as the auxiliary verb when forming the perfect tense: ... bin ich ... gewesen.
- But your substantive question is whether you should use the perfect tense in the main clause here at all, and the answer to that is no if you're talking about something still ongoing, not something in the past.

So the sentence you want is: Seit(dem) ich bei dieser neuen Stelle zu arbeiten angefangen habe, bin ich dienstags immer sehr beschäftigt.

If you actually are talking about having been busy in the past, but not anymore, then you do want "... sehr beschäftigt gewesen" in the end, but it doesn't sound like that is what you are trying to say.

Comment: Seitdem isn't formal nor is it rare.

Answer (score 1):

Seitdem ich bei dieser neuen Stelle zu arbeiten angefangen habe, bin ich dienstags immer sehr beschäftigt.

"Bei dieser neuen Stelle" - Stelle is feminine dative, therefore "dieser" not "diese".

"Diese neue Stelle ist sehr interessant.".
"Die Arbeitsstunden dieser neuen Stelle sind viel zu lang".
"Ich habe bei dieser neuen Stelle angefangen".
"Er hat mir diese neue Stelle angeboten".

And now a masculine word:

"Dieser neue Job ist sehr interessant.".
"Die Arbeitsstunden dieses neuen Jobs sind viel zu lang".
"Ich habe bei diesem neuen Job angefangen".
"Er hat mir diesen neuen Job angeboten"

"Ich habe zu arbeiten angefangen" instead of "Ich habe arbeiten angefangen".

"Besetzt" is the wrong word. "Besetzt" means occupied (like a toilet that is occupied), there is a person occupying the space. "Sehr beschäftigt" is quite good. Or you could translate it more non-literal "Dienstags habe ich sehr wenig freie Zeit".

Comment: Tippfehler: "Arbeitsstunder"

Comment: Thanks. Fixed. 15 characters needed...

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation:

> Seit ich meinen neuen Job / meine neue Stelle angetreten habe, habe ich am Dienstag sehr viel zu tun.